# Changes in data at Google Drive in WhatsApp backup

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have scheduled WhatsApp Auto-backup at Google Drive using WhatsApp.

[image]

Apart from this, I delete unwanted media files (image & video) from the WhatsApp Folder in Gallery.

Will backup file at Google Drive keep deleted media file or it will be deleted in next schedule?

And in case of Restore backup file, will I get all deleted media files?

Please check and clarify.

Thank you in advance.

Regards
FewL

Comment: afaik google drive backups are just snapshots and not merged but replaced